# error when starting servers

Tags: wso2, appserver

AS I start any of the wso2 server, the log prints:

```
[2013-06-19 08:51:18,112] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.internal.BootupValidationActivator} -  Error occured w
hile starting Bootup Validation Activator
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: f
```

how to solve this issue? thanks!

Comment: There seems to be some error in your config_validation.xml did you do any changes on that?.

Comment: no, but I will check if something wrong, thanks, pulasthi

Comment: Did you build the product from source or you used released distribution during your task.